# How to query from Multiple Tables

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I have three Models

```
 @Entity(foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = SelfHelpGroup::class, parentColumns = ["shgId"], childColumns = ["shgId"], onDelete = CASCADE), ForeignKey(entity = Member::class, parentColumns = ["memberId"], childColumns = ["memberId"], onDelete = CASCADE)])
 data class Committee(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @SerializedName("committeeId")
    val committeeId: Int?= null,
    @SerializedName("shgId")
    val shgId: Int?,
    @SerializedName("memberId")
    val memberId: Int?,
    @SerializedName("date")
    val date: String?
)


@Entity(tableName = "Member", foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = SelfHelpGroup::class, parentColumns = ["shgId"], childColumns = ["shgId"], onDelete = CASCADE), ForeignKey(entity = Role::class, parentColumns = ["roleId"], childColumns = ["roleId"], onDelete = CASCADE)])
data class Member(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @SerializedName("memberId")
    val memberId: Int ?= null,
    @SerializedName("shgId")
    val shgId: Int,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("address")
    val address: String,
    @SerializedName("phoneNumber")
    val phoneNumber: String,
    @SerializedName("emailId")
    val emailId: String,
    @SerializedName("roleId")
    val roleId: Int?,
    @SerializedName("password")
    val password: String?
)

@Entity(foreignKeys = [
    ForeignKey(entity = Committee::class, parentColumns = ["committeeId"], childColumns = ["committeeId"], onDelete = CASCADE),
    ForeignKey(entity = Member::class, parentColumns = ["memberId"], childColumns = ["memberId"], onDelete = CASCADE),
])
data class Attendance(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @SerializedName("attendanceId")
    val attendanceId: Int?= null,
    @SerializedName("committeeId")
    val committeeId: Int,
    @SerializedName("memberId")
    val memberId: Int,
    /*@SerializedName("status")
    val status: AttendanceStatus,*/
    @SerializedName("isPresent")
    var isPresent: Boolean = false,
    @SerializedName("leaveApplied")
    var leaveApplied: Boolean = false
)
```

Relation between 3 models :

Any member can host a committee.
The hosted memberId is saved in the table Member.
Other members can join the committee.
To track the attendance of these members, we are using the Table Attendance.

So I need help queriying the data in such a way that the result structure would look like below

```
data class CommitteeDetails (
    val committeeId: Int,
    val member: Member,
    val attendances: List<Attendance>,
    val dateTime: String
)
```

Since there are more than many committees, I need to query to get Listof CommitteeDetails

```
val committees = List<CommitteeDetails>()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use:-

```
data class CommitteeDetails (
    //val committeeId: Int, /* part of the Committee so get the Committee in it's entireity */
    @Embedded
    val committee: Committee,
    @Relation(entity = Member::class, parentColumn = "memberId", entityColumn = "memberId")
    val member: Member,
    @Relation(entity = Attendance::class, parentColumn = "committeeId", entityColumn = "committeeId")
    val attendances: List<Attendance>
    //val dateTime: String
)
```

This does then retrieve a little more information but the Query is very simple as you just query the committee table.

e.g. to get ALL Committees with the Member and the attendances then you can use

```
@Transaction 
@Query("SELECT * FROM committee")
```

- `@Tranaction` is not mandatory but if not used will result in a warning e.g.

  ```
    warning: The return value includes a POJO with a `@Relation`. It is usually desired to annotate this method with `@Transaction` to avoid possibility of inconsistent results between the POJO and its relations. See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction.html for details.
  ```
- This is because `@Relation` results in Room effectively running subqueries to obtain the related items. Note that using `@Relation` will return **ALL** the related items for the `@Embedded`.

---

---

**IF** you wanted to get exactly what you have asked for then it's a little more convoluted as you would then have to not use @Embedded for the Committee and thus you could then not use @Relation.

In theory you would SELECT FROM the committee table, JOIN the member table and also JOIN the attendance table. The issue is that the result is the cartesian map so for every attendance per committee you would get a result that contained the committee columns (id and date) the member columns (all to build the full Member class) and all the columns from the attendance. However, the issue, is then building the CommitteeDetails.

However, you can mimic how room works and just get the desired committee column along with the member columns and then invoke a subquery to obtain the related attendances (potentially filtering them).

So say you have (wanting a List of these as the end result):-

```
data class CommitteeDetailsExact (
    val committeeId: Int,
    val member: Member,
    val attendances: List<Attendance>,
    val dateTime: String
)
```

The to facilitate the initial extraction of the committee and members columns you could have another POJO such as:-

```
data class CommitteeIdAndDateAsDateTimeWithMember(
    val committeeId: Int,
    @Embedded
    val member: Member,
    val dateTime: String
)
```

To facilitate extracting the data you could have functions such as:-

```
@Query("SELECT committee.committeeId, committee.date AS dateTime, member.* FROM committee JOIN member ON committee.memberId = member.memberId")
fun getCommitteeExactLessAttendances(): List<CommitteeIdAndDateAsDateTimeWithMember>
@Query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE committeeId=:committeeId")
fun getCommitteeAttendances(committeeId: Int): List<Attendance>
```

To obtain the end result then the above functions need to be used together, so you could have a function such as:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("")
fun getExactCommitteeDetails(): List<CommitteeDetailsExact> {
    var rv = arrayListOf<CommitteeDetailsExact>()
    for (ciadadwm in getExactCommitteeDetails()) {
        rv.add(CommitteeDetailsExact(ciadadwm.committeeId,ciadadwm.member,getCommitteeAttendances(ciadadwm.committeeId),ciadadwm.dateTime))
    }
    return rv.toList()
}
```

This will:-

- return the desired list of committee details *(albeit `List<CommitteeDetailsExact>` to suite the two answers given)*
- run as a single transaction (the `@Query(")` enables Room to apply the `@Transaction`)
- Obtains the list of committee and member columns an then
- Loops through the list extract the respective list of attendances
- in short it, in this case, is very much similar to the first answer other than limiting the columns extracted from the committee table.